# Pretty table python module with variable number of rows

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-2.7

Is there a way to produce a table in a txt file using pretty table python module, using an i variable for the row count for the case I do not know the number of rows from the begining?
For example I have the following table:

```
mytable = prettytable.PrettyTable()
mytable.add_column("Column1", [my_list_a[0], my_list_a[1], my_list_a[2]])
mytable.add_column("Column2", [my_list_b[0], my_list_b[1], my_list_b[2]])
mystringmytable = mytable.get_string
f.write(mystringmytable )
```

But let' s say that I do not know from the begining the length of my lists, my_list_a & my_list_b.
So, how could I modify the code concerning the above case?
I am using python 2.7 for qgis2.10 plugin development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you are looking for is the **[list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)** functionality for Python.

instead of creating a list using hardcoded indexes you can rewrite it in a more generic form :

```
[ i for i in mylist ]
```

So I think you can rewrite

```
mytable.add_column("Column1", [my_list_a[0], my_list_a[1], my_list_a[2])
```

as

```
mytable.add_column("Column1",[ item in item for mylist ])
```

which is more generic and provides the functionality you are looking for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#List_comprehensions
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but isn't `[item in item for mylist]` just a copy of `mylist`?

Comment: nickves I get a syntax error like this, but I will study list comprehensions.. thank you

Comment: @Eleftheria the syntax error is likely from the the missing left parenthesis `)` in the last statement. I think you should try just passing the list itself, i.e., `mytable.add_column("Column1", mylist)`

Comment: @PaulH you are correct in both accounts!. It is a copy. It was the first thing that poped into mind. Using `mylist` should work equally.

Comment: @Paul H I gor the error with parenthesis, I had not copy from here.. anyway I just passed the list itself as you proposed and is working fine!!  thank you!!

Comment: >>> [i for i in mylist] == mylist
True